# Getting a radio button's checked state in jquery with radio button ID

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, html

I am trying to get a radio button's checked status in jquery but I am always getting false/NO while debugging.

**This is my view code :**

```
<label>@Html.RadioButton("AlternateEmailRdoBtn", "YES", true, new { id="SendMailRegMailID" }) Mail report to registered mail id</label><br />
<label>@Html.RadioButton("AlternateEmailRdoBtn", "NO", false, new { id="SendMailAltMailID" }) Mail report to &nbsp @Html.TextBox("AlternateEmailTextBox","", new { id="AlternateEmailTextBox" })</label>
```

**In Jquery :**

```
var checkedstate = $('input[id=SendMailAltMailID]:checked').val();
```

This value is always returning `false`. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Because the radio button with `id="SendMailAltMailID"` is the 2nd one and that's the only one you checking (although it will return "NO"). You want `$('input[name="AlternateEmailRdoBtn"]:checked').val();` to get the value of the checked radio button

Comment: `$('input[name=AlternateEmailRdoBtn]:checked').val();` is still returning "NO"

Comment: Not if the first one is checked :)

Comment: It's working the other way round though. If I check second, it returns "NO" and if I check first it returns "YES". Is it possible to get it as bool value? Even it is "YES" in jquery, when I get it in controller, it remains as `false`. @StephenMuecke

Comment: That's what its supposed to return :) - the value of the 1st one is "YES" and the 2nd is "NO"

Comment: Got the point now. Was unaware of its exact working. It is supposed to return the "VALUE" provided to get which one is checked. I changed it to "false" and "true" as per my requirement.

Comment: I assume you thought the 3rd parameter was the value? Its sets the `checked` state and you can remove that - its ignored if your binding to a model property which I assume `AlternateEmailRdoBtn` is

Comment: Yes. Exactly. I thought it would return `true` for 1st and `false` for 2nd. I am not binding to the model. So I need the default checked state too.

Comment: In that case, there is really no point using `RadioButton` - you may as well just use `<input type="radio" name="AlternateEmailRdoBtn" value="true" />` and ditto with `value="false" checked`

Comment: Ok. Thanks for the support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got an answer to my question as per Stephen's comment. I added two radio buttons :

1. For default email id, and set its value to `false` and default checked state to `true`.
2. For alternate email id, set its value to `true` and default checked state to `false`.

```html
<label>@Html.RadioButton("AlternateEmailRdoBtn", false, true, new { @class="AltEmailRdoBtn", id="SendMailRegMailID" }) Mail report to registered mail id</label>
<label>@Html.RadioButton("AlternateEmailRdoBtn", true, false, new { @class="AltEmailRdoBtn", id="SendMailAltMailID" }) Mail report to other email :</label>
```

When below code is executed, it returns the value `true` from second radio button. ie `altEmailcheckedStatus = true` for alternate email ID and `altEmailcheckedStatus = false` for default email id.

```
var altEmailcheckedStatus = $('input[name=AlternateEmailRdoBtn]:checked').val();
```

Answer (score 0):

you can get value of radio button by using

$('input[name=AlternateEmailRdoBtn]:checked').val();